# Neo4j Java VM Tuning (v2.3 Community)

Tags: neo4j, jvm

From what I can tell I'm having an issue with my Neo4j v2.3 Community Java VM adding items to the Old Gen Heap and never being able to Garbage Collecting them.

Here is a detailed outline of the situation.

I have a PHP file which calls the Dropbox Delta API and writes out the file structure to my Neo4j Database. Each call to Delta returns a 2000 Item data sets of which I pull out the information I need, the following is an example of what that query looks like with just one item, usually I send in full batches of 2000 items as it gave me the best results.

```
***Following is an example Query***
MERGE (c:Cloud { type:'Dropbox', id_user:'15', id_account:''})
WITH c
UNWIND [
    { parent_shared_folder_id:488417928, rev:'15e1d1caa88',.......}
    ] 
AS items MERGE (i:Item { id:items.path, id_account:'', id_user:'15', type:'Dropbox' })
ON Create SET i = { id:items.path, id_account:'', id_user:'15', is_dir:items.is_dir, name:items.name, description:items.description, size:items.size, created_at:items.created_at, modified:items.modified, processed:1446769779, type:'Dropbox'}
ON Match  SET i+= { id:items.path, id_account:'', id_user:'15', is_dir:items.is_dir, name:items.name, description:items.description, size:items.size, created_at:items.created_at, modified:items.modified, processed:1446769779, type:'Dropbox'}
MERGE (p:Item {id_user:'15', id:items.parentPath, id_account:'', type:'Dropbox'})
MERGE (p)-[:Contains]->(i)
MERGE (c)-[:Owns]->(i)


***The query is sent via Everyman****

static function makeQuery($client, $qry) {
    return new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, $qry);
}
```

This works fine and generally from start to finish takes 8-10 seconds to run.

The Dropbox account I am accessing contains around 35000 items, and takes around 18 runs of my PHP to populate my Neo4j Database with the folder/file structure of the dropbox account.

With every run of this PHP, around 50mb of items are added to the Neo4j JVM Old Gen heap, 30mb of that is not removed by GC.

The end result is obviously the VM runs out of memory and gets stuck in a constant state of GC throttling.

I have tried a range of Neo4j VM settings, as well as an update from Neo4j v2.2.5 to v2.3, which actually has appeared to make the problem worse.

My current settings are as follows,

```
-server
-Xms4096m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:NewSize=3072m
-XX:MaxNewSize=3072m
-XX:SurvivorRatio=1
```

I am testing on a windows 10 PC with 8GB of ram and an i5 2.5GHz quad core. Java 1.8.0_60

Any info on how to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated. 
Cheers, Jack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the new size to 1024m

change your settings to:

```
-server
-Xms4096m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:NewSize=1024m
```

It is most likely that the size of your tx grows too large.

I recommend sending each of the **parents** in separately, so instead of the UNWIND sent one statement each.

Make sure to use the new transactional http endpoint, I recommend to go wit [neoclient](https://github.com/neoxygen/neo4j-neoclient) instead of Neo4jPHP

**You should also use parameters instead of literal values!!!**

And don't repeeat user-id and type etc. properties on every item.

Are you sure you want to connect everything to `c` not just the root of the directory structure? I would do the latter.

```
MERGE (c:Cloud:Dropbox { id_user:{userId}})

MERGE (p:Item:Dropbox {id:{parentPath}})
// owning the parent should be good enough
MERGE (c)-[:Owns]->(p)

WITH c
UNWIND {items} as item
MERGE (i:Item:Dropbox { id:item.path})
ON Create SET i += { is_dir:item.is_dir, name:item.name, created_at:item.created_at }
SET i += { description:item.description, size:item.size, modified:items.modified, processed:timestamp()}
MERGE (p)-[:Contains]->(i);
```

Make sure to use 2.3.0 for best MERGE performance for relationships.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the problem appears to of been reduced.

So far we have manged to convert the query to use parameters and updated the server settings. And are now looking at switching neo4j clients.

A large number of items are still reaching the old Gen which concerns me as the neo4j performance tuning guide reads 

'the heap should ideally be sized and tuned such that transaction and query state never makes it to the old generation.'

After running the PHP for mentioned with the changes we still end up with ~700mb added to the Old Gen, but it at least now is all removed with GC

Comment: Also try to update to 2.3.1 when it comes out in a few days.